# Multisite setup on Ovh

Tags: php, hosting, shared-hosting, multisite, ovh

I have a website on OVH web hosting.I want to add one more website to it.I have added TXT file ON DNS area.After this, I also added parameters that OVH has given to me to activate multisite like A record as well.But this is not working for me as it adds domain name as a subdomain like x.ovhsupport.fr but I want it to be added like x.fr a full domain name.And it shows me as a site not installed yet but the files exist.I want it as a full domain name.I don't know how to do it Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Is your domain registered with OVH or is it an external domain?
An internal domain can be automatically configured by OVH, you should consider a transfer if it's an external domain. Or you can refer to this step-by-step procedure in [OVH docs](https://docs.ovh.com/fr/hosting/multisites-configurer-un-multisite-sur-mon-hebergement-web/).